# CS0656: Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.InvokeMember' When adding IronPDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, ironpdf

I have an old version of Umbraco, 7.4.5 running on net framework 4.8.  When adding IronPDF and trying to load `http://localhost/umbraco` the page won't load (run-time error) because presumably, it is trying to reference `Microsoft.CSharp` from IronPDF via something dynamic in the umbraco backend/razor views/etc.

I've tried the following:

- Reinstall iron pdf
- Reinstall umbraco
- Remove the Microsoft.CSharp and add via Nuget
- Aliased all the IronPDF references to something besides global

If I remove IronPDF, umbraco works as expected.

How can I work around this issue?

```
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.8.9032.0

for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240

warning CS1685: The predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\d92acae1\c833fd19\assembly\dl3\8f945f7d\00a6d0bb_f2e5d901\IronPdf.DLL'
warning CS1685: The predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpBinderFlags' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\d92acae1\c833fd19\assembly\dl3\8f945f7d\00a6d0bb_f2e5d901\IronPdf.DLL'
warning CS1685: The predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfo' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\d92acae1\c833fd19\assembly\dl3\8f945f7d\00a6d0bb_f2e5d901\IronPdf.DLL'
warning CS1685: The predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpArgumentInfoFlags' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\d92acae1\c833fd19\assembly\dl3\8f945f7d\00a6d0bb_f2e5d901\IronPdf.DLL'
warning CS1685: The predefined type 'System.ObsoleteAttribute' is defined in multiple assemblies in the global alias; using definition from 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll'
error CS0656: Missing compiler required member 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.InvokeMember'
c:\projects\git\web\umbraco\Views\Default.cshtml(71,105): error CS1969: One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?
c:\projects\git\web\umbraco\Views\Default.cshtml(76,76): error CS1969: One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the zip package or installer of IronPdf instead. You can download the zip packages for different operating systems below:

- [Windows](https://ironpdf.com/packages/IronPdf.zip)
- [Linux](https://ironpdf.com/packages/IronPdf.Linux.zip)
- [macOs](https://ironpdf.com/packages/IronPdf.MacOs.zip)

Visit the [IronPdf docs](https://ironpdf.com/docs/) to learn more.